# Question on a generalized Dirichlet series

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Given the generalized Dirichlet series
$$S(x) =\sum_{(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2}e^{-x\sqrt{n^2+m^2}} $$
is there any way to solve the equation
$$2S(2x)=S(x)$$
for $x\in\mathbb{R}$? I am only interested in positive real solutions (unless I need to find complex ones in order to find real ones). It is not hard to show that this series converges for $x>0$, and one can show that solving the above equation is equivalent to solving
$$\sum_{\gcd(n,m)=1} \frac{1}{1+e^{x\sqrt{n^2+m^2}}}=1.$$
However, while this gives better estimates when one approximates both sums by a finite series, it has a trickier form (at least it seems so to me). I know little about generalized Dirichlet series and was wondering if someone knew anything about $S(x)$ as defined above as it looks like a natural function that should show up in other contexts.